# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null functions.js:29 changeNameToLetters functions.js:29 onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Hi everybody I am getting this error in my console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null functions.js:29
changeNameToLetters functions.js:29
onclick
```

I tried searching for that but I am new to javascript and am not quite sure of how to fix it. Initially I had my script in the head tag and switched it to right before the ending body tag to see if it was an error with how everything was loading but unfortunately it still didn't work. I checked my spelling of my id and the text within my h3 tag and they seem fine to me. Like I said though I am very new to javascript and probably overlooking something obvious.

Thanks for your input!

Here is my html.

```
<body>
<h3 id"changeH3Text" onClick="changeNameToLetters()">
Regular Keyboard on Hover
</h3> 
<div id="keyboardContainer" class="keyboard">......</div>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function changeNameToLetters(){
//keyboard container variables
var  keyboardState= document.getElementById("keyboardContainer");
var currentClass = keyboardState.className;

//h3 text variables
var h3Text=document.getElementById("changeH3Text");
var currentText=h3Text.innerHTML;


    if (currentClass == "keyboard_normal" && currentText =="Tool Name on Hover" ) { 
    keyboardState.className = "keyboard";
    h3Text.innerHTML="Regular Keyboard on Hover";   
} //end if

else {
    keyboardState.className = "keyboard_normal"; 
    h3Text.innerHTML="Tool Name on Hover"; 
} //end else
} //End function
```

Comment: You are missing a `=` in between `id` and `changeH3Text` in HTML. Adding it should fix.

Comment: @Harry Oh My GOD! Thank you!! Your a life saver! Guess I have been looking at it too long and needed a fresh perspective, You are my hero! Everything works perfectly now :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Harry is right

```
<h3 id="changeH3Text" onClick="changeNameToLetters()">
```

id did not have the = after it.

Comment: lol thanks Ruddy, I feel kind of dumb that I missed it. I fixed it and everything is working great now :)

Comment: Ah don't feel dumb, it happens to all of us. :)